# Can't access enum values inside Switch Case / Java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I can't access my enum variables in my switch-case statement:

```
public enum Country {

FRANCE(0, "France"), SPAIN(1, "Spain");
private final int code;
private final String name;
Country(int code, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
}
public int getCode() {
    return code;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

In another class there is this code :

```
public Drawable getFlag(){
    Drawable d = null;
    switch(country_id){
    case Country.FRANCE.getCode():
        break;
    }
    return d;
}
```

But the problem is that when i type Country, there is only class or this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions in the `case` statements must be constant values.
One (commonly used) way to approach your problem is by creating a function that gets the enum from the numeric code:

```
public enum Country {
...
public static Country getCountry(int countryCode) {
    for(Country country : Country.values()) {
        if(country.code == countryCode) {
            return country;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Then you'll be able to do the switch on the enum:

```
switch(Country.getCountry(country_id)){
case Country.FRANCE:
    break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`case` labels in a `switch` statement need be constants

Answer (score 1):

The case expressions must be compile time constant expressions. Your enum instance's variables are constants, but not compile time constants.

> We call a variable, of primitive type or type String, that is final
>   and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28) a
>   constant variable. Whether a variable is a constant variable or not
>   may have implications with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1),
>   binary compatibility (§13.1, §13.4.9) and definite assignment (§16).